# How to filter greater than in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

```
type Person {
    firstName: String!,
    lastName: String!,
    age: Int!
}
```

How to query all people what are older than 18?

Answer (score 8):

- [**Graphql will not include these complex filters** atleast for
  **DECADE** as graphql is acting to be **library**.](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/341)
- And libraries become part of other libraries and framework.They don't
  become framework
- Right now to use graphql to full extend you can combine it with ORM'S
  like Hasura Or Graphile Or Prisma

### [**Hasura**](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/query-filters.html#greater-than-or-less-than-operators-gt-lt-gte-lte)

```
query {
  article(
    where: {rating: {_gte: 4}}
  ) {
    id
    title
    rating
  }
}
```

### [**Prisma**](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/prisma-api/queries-ahwee4zaey#object-queries)

```
query {
  posts(where: {
    AND: [{
      title_in: ["My biggest Adventure", "My latest Hobbies"]
    }]
  }) {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

**Advice**
Do not use graphql directly/independently ,use it with above orm's

Comment: [Graphile](https://www.graphile.org/) is insane!

Answer (score 7):

It probably depends on the backend you are using but e.g. in graph.cool you could something like this:

```
query {
  allPersons(filter: {
    age_gt: 18
  }) {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using [Prisma](https://prisma.io) as backend, you could use the greater than operator (`_gt`), like so:

```
query {
  persons(where: {age_gt: 18}) {
    firstName
    lastName
    age
  }
}
```

You can also use other operators like:

- `_gt` (greater than)
- `_lt` (less than)
- `_gte` (greater than or equal to)
- `_lte` (less than or equal to)
- `_in` (equal to)
- `_not_in` (not equal to)

They are compatible with any data types like Integer, Float, Double, Text, Boolean, Date, etc.